# How exactly does AWS EC2 count hourly costs?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Simple question:

If I had six identical EC2 instances process data for exactly ten minutes and turn off would I be charged six hours or one hour?

Comment: A related question for further reading: [Amazon EC2 pricing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882240/amazon-ec2-pricing-question).

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** EC2 and EBS are now based on usage [down to the second](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-per-second-billing-for-ec2-instances-and-ebs-volumes/)

**Old answer**
Granularity for changes are measure down to the hour.

From the AWS pricing site http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/:

> Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time
> an instance is launched until it is terminated or stopped. Each
> partial instance-hour consumed will be billed as a full hour.

Unless you are calculating time to be under a threshold for a free tier, the second you use an EC2  instance you're charged for the full hour.  If you go one second over the first hour, your charged for a full second hour.

One caveat: Spot Instances.

If spot instances are interrupted by AWS (not you) before reaching a full hour use, you're not charged at all.  If you interrupt the spot instance, you're charge for the partial hour usage (which is a full hour rounded up as per the on-demand instances).

Comment: I even found that stopping and starting a single instance multiple times within a 60 minute period still counts as multiple hours: http://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-stop-start

Comment: @EricHammond interesting.  I as not aware of that.  Is this still the case and does it include just rebooting the instance?

Comment: A simple reboot does not start a new instance hour. A stop/start does.

Comment: Please note that this response is top one, but not actual(see the other response below with 2017 updates. This may mislead to those who prepare for AWS certification. @Ray, could you please update the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

AWS has introduced per second billing for EC2/EBS effective October 2, 2017.

[New EC2 Billing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-per-second-billing-for-ec2-instances-and-ebs-volumes/)

Comment: If you were wondering (I was), "List prices and Spot Market prices are still listed on a per-hour basis, but bills are calculated down to the second", Jeff Barr [explains](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-per-second-billing-for-ec2-instances-and-ebs-volumes/).

Answer (score 0):

You always get 750 hours per month for all your ec2 instances.

Different cases:

Case 1: Your have created and running one instance for 10 minutes.And then stopped.

It will be counted as 1 hour.

Case 2: Your have two running instances for each for 5 or 10 minutes and then stopped. It will be counted as 2 hours.

Case 3: You have one instance running for 10 minutes, then stopped and then again started for 10 or 5 minutes. It will be counted as 2 hours.

You can only use t2.micro servers and some limited OS in free tier.

This way, you can prevent your unwanted billing.

I hope, this has cleared some doubts.

Note: This is just my understanding till today. Please check their(aws) pricing docs for updated information.